# How to create in Django an object of a model while creating another of a different model?

Tags: python, django, django-models

It sounds pretty confusing but I will put my code here for a better understanding of my problem. I want to create a new object of Model Product every time I create an object of Model Client. I tried to overwrite the save method but it didn't work.

```
    class Product(models.Model):
       text = CharField( ... )

    class Client(models.Model):
       name = CharField( ... )
    
       ** method here to create a new Product object when a Client object is created ?**
```

Edit: The main problem with overwriting the save method is that the Product object is created after editing the client object, not after creating.

Answer (score 0):

I used post_save signal to have a better handling, I must specify that I needed the pk of the Client object I've created in order to create the Product object.

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Client)
def function_to_do_new_object(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    obj = Product(text="Hello", id_of_client=int(instance.pk))
    obj.save()
```